# Solve broadcasting error without for loop, speed up code

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, matrix, scipy

I may be misunderstanding how broadcasting works in Python, but I am still running into errors.

`scipy` offers a number of "special functions" which take in two arguments, in particular the `eval_XX(n, x[,out])` functions.
See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html

My program uses many orthogonal polynomials, so I must evaluate these polynomials at distinct points. Let's take the concrete example `scipy.special.eval_hermite(n, x, out=None)`.

I would like the `x` argument to be a matrix shape `(50, 50)`. Then, I would like to evaluate each entry of this matrix at a number of points. Let's define `n` to be an a numpy array `narr = np.arange(10)` (where we have imported `numpy` as `np`, i.e. `import numpy as np`).

So, calling

```
scipy.special.eval_hermite(narr, matrix)
```

should return Hermitian polynomials `H_0(matrix), H_1(matrix), H_2(matrix)`, etc. Each `H_X(matrix)` is of the shape `(50,50)`, the shape of the original input matrix.

Then, I would like to sum these values. So, I call

```
matrix1 = np.sum( [scipy.eval_hermite(narr, matrix)], axis=0 )
```

but I get a broadcasting error!

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (50,50)
```

I can solve this with a for loop, i.e.

```
matrix2 = np.sum( [scipy.eval_hermite(i, matrix) for i in narr], axis=0)
```

This gives me the correct answer, and the output `matrix2.shape = (50,50)`. But using this for loop slows down my code, big time. Remember, we are working with entries of matrices.

Is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Comment: `narr` isn't that big - just 10 entries - so why is this so slow? The list comprehension should just produce a list of 10 arrays, which `np.sum` should sum pretty quickly.

Comment: @nneonneo I am using this for an easy example. Actually, some matrices are shape `(1000, 1000)`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter unless your `narr` is huge, and I'm not sure why it would be - it's just the order of the polynomial, and you shouldn't be needing 1000-degree Hermite polynomials.

Comment: @nneonneo At most the `narr` is of length 100. So yes, it does slow down the code. A lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval_hermite` broadcasts `n` with `x`, then evaluates H<sub>n</sub>(x) at each point. Thus, the output shape will be the result of broadcasting `n` with `x`. So, if you want to make this work, you'll have to make `n` and `x` have compatible shapes:

```
import scipy.special as ss
import numpy as np
matrix = np.ones([100,100]) # example
narr = np.arange(10) # example
ss.eval_hermite(narr[:,None,None], matrix).shape # => (10, 100, 100)
```

But note that this might actually be faster:

```
out = np.zeros_like(matrix)
for n in narr:
    out += ss.eval_hermite(n, matrix)
```

In testing, it appears to be between 5-10% faster than `np.sum(...)` of above.

Comment: Broadcasting rules when applied to multiplying arrays in a summation gets confusing for me. If I understand correctly, the shape of ss.eval_hermite is now `(10,100,100)`. Isn't this a different result than my operation above? (In that example, it would be `matrix2.shape=(50,50`, but here it would be `shape=(100,100)`)
Further question: what is I need to do another summation with `ss.eval_hermite(narr[:,None,None], matrix)`, but this time my array of ints for `n` is 20 values. I'm going to run into the same problem, aren't I?

Comment: The sizes of `matrix` and `narr` are just examples above. You can define `matrix` and `narr` any way you want (provided they are 2D and 1D respectively) and the `ss.eval_hermite(narr[:,None,None], matrix).shape` will behave correctly. The technical explanation is that the `[:,None,None]` adds two extra size-1 dimensions to `narr`, making it broadcast-compatible with `matrix` (by having the last dimensions of both be compatible).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for these functions is skimpy, and a lot of the code is compiled, so this is just based on experimentation:

```
special.eval_hermite(n, x, out=None)
```

`n` apparently is a scalar or array of integers.  `x` can be an array of floats.

`special.eval_hermite(np.ones(5,int)[:,None],np.ones(6))` gives me a `(5,6)` result.  This is the same shape as what I'd get from `np.ones(5,int)[:,None] * np.ones(6)`.

The `np.ones(5,int)[:,None]` is a `(5,1)` array, `np.ones(6)` a `(6,)`, which for this purpose is equivalent of `(1,6)`.  Both can be expanded to `(5,6)`.

So as best I can tell, broadcasting rules in these `special` functions is the same as for operators like `*`.

---

Since `special.eval_hermite(nar[:,None,None], x)` produces a `(10,50,50)`, you just apply `sum` to axis 0 of that to produce the `(50,50)`.

```
special.eval_hermite(nar[:,Nar,Nar], x).sum(axis=0)
```

Like I wrote before, the same broadcasting (and summing) rules apply for this `hermite` as they do for a basic operation like `*`.

Comment: Please see my comment to @nneonneo below.

Comment: Just apply `sum(axis=0)` to that `(N, M,M)` result.  Same as broadcasting and summing with `*`.